# Download Blob file into Memory Stream from Azure using C#

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read a blob from Azure using C# Console application. I can download the blob file to my local machine and read it but when I am trying to download it to memory stream it is throwing an error as attached.[image]

I want to directly read my blob file instead of downloading it to local machine as I have to deploy it in Azure. Any suggestions on it?

```
var storageaccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), true);
        var blobclient = storageaccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobclient.GetContainerReference("");
       // var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
       var blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobFileName);
        using (var memorystream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlobReference.DownloadToStream(memorystream);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is because you're wrapping it in a using statement. Try the following:

```
var storageaccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), true);
var blobclient = storageaccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobclient.GetContainerReference("");
// var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
var blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobFileName);
var memorystream = new MemoryStream();

blockBlobReference.DownloadToStream(memorystream);
byte[] content = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, but Blob downloaded successfully.

your screenshot just shows the variable in Visual Studio debugger, and it looks like the error doesn't actually occurred.

In screenshot, `MemoryStream`, `CanTimeout` property set to `false`.
So, it seems that `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` throw exceptions only because MemoryStream does not support them.

Reference:

- [Stream.ReadTimeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readtimeout?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Stream_ReadTimeout)

Please note that the exception won't occurred until you use `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` properties.